# wxPython re-sizing wxGrid column weight

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to build a wxGrid and set it's columns size, but it won't work -

```
class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1,size=(705, 333),pos=(44, 84))
        self.CreateGrid(1,6)
        for i in xrange(6):
            self.SetColSize(i,300)
            self.ForceRefresh()
```

Comment: You want 6 columns of 300 pixels each to fit in a grid with a total width of 705?  Sounds like a pretty tight fit and I imagine that wx would not let you,  What final sizes do you want for the grid and each of its columns?

Comment: So, checking just told you you cannot have 1,800 pixels of columns in a 705 pixels grid -- good!  Now, *what* are you trying to accomplish, beyond checking the arithmetic in question?